# ClassNotFoundException in maven project of spring

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

I just learning springframework currently.and I tried to build a maven project for springframework.and when I selected "run with"->"maven test",some error .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [class org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createBootstrapContext(BootstrapUtils.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:98)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
```

I have Introducing maven dependencies of spring-test and spring-bean .so I can understand why it was happend.every guy who can tell me where it was wrong

It's my depedencies

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
  <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's my interface and java Bean，all of them in src/main/soundsystem package

```
public interface CompactDisc {
    void play();
}

@Component
public class SgtPeppers implements CompactDisc {
    private String title = "Sgt title";
    private String artist = "the Beatles";
    public void play() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Playing " + title + " by " + artist);
    }
}
```

my springConfiguration class,also in src/main/soundsystem package

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {
}
```

my Test class , in src/test/soundsystem package

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `CompactDisc` actually a Spring Bean? Besides that, it is very hard to make up what your actual question is here...

Comment: I just modified my question, and all the source was here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I was getting:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass

The problem was that 'spring-test' was not using the 'spring-beans' dependency as specified but instead the 'spring' library that was being used by another dependency.
Execute `mvn dependency:tree` to find out your dependencies.

Comment: all the mvn dependencies were in this question description(all the spring dependency is **4.3.1.RELEASE**),and when I execute ```mvn dependency:tree```,the msg "BUILD SUCCESS " showed on console

Comment: I just solved this problem when I tried to change spring maven dependencies from **4.3.1.RELEASE**  to **4.3.3.RELEASE**...